# How to confirm NUMA?

Tags: java, linux, numa

How can I confirm that a host is NUMA-aware?  The [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#numa) says that NUMA-awareness starts at kernel 2.6.19, but the [NUMA man page](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/numa.7.html) says that it was introduced with 2.6.14.  I'd like to be sure that a Java process started with `-XX:+UseNUMA` is actually taking advantage of something.

Checking for the numa_maps, I see that I have them:

```
# find /proc -name numa_maps
/proc/1/task/1/numa_maps
/proc/1/numa_maps
/proc/2/task/2/numa_maps
/proc/2/numa_maps
/proc/3/task/3/numa_maps
```

Though my kernel is behind what Oracle states:

```
# uname -sr
Linux 2.6.18-92.el5
```

I'm currently using 64-bit jdk1.6.0_29 on RHEL5.1.

Comment: Did you consider upgrading your kernel to something more recent?

Comment: RHEL 5.1 (2007-11-07) is pretty old, perhaps its time to upgrade.

Comment: @Peter In my experience the people working with NUMA processors usually aren't the ones in charge of updating the software and have to go through quite a lot of bureaucracy to get it updated. Just saw a *python 2.4* install last week on a supercomputer with 2k cores..

Comment: @aix I assume that could be the case on multi processor machines on a single MB (not sure there), but then not many people have those either and on a single processor Sandy bridge all CPUs should have the same latency to the whole memory? I'm pretty sure Intel describes SB processors as SMPs

Comment: @Voo: Fair point. I've withdrawn my remark.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The presence of those /proc files indicates that your linux kernel is numa-aware. Don't concern yourself too much comparing version numbers, as, particularly with Oracle / RHEL kernels, the vendors port/backport many features without keeping the version string "up to date".

Other ways of testing the same thing:

```
$ grep NUMA=y /boot/config-`uname -r`
CONFIG_NUMA=y
CONFIG_K8_NUMA=y
CONFIG_X86_64_ACPI_NUMA=y
CONFIG_ACPI_NUMA=y

$ numactl --hardware
available: 2 nodes (0-1)
node 0 size: 18156 MB
node 0 free: 9053 MB
node 1 size: 18180 MB
node 1 free: 6853 MB
node distances:
node   0   1
  0:  10  20
  1:  20  10
```

Comment: rhel's backporting was my on my mind as well.  good call with /boot/config

Comment: but does that imply the JVM uses it? is there any logging to indicate numa is in use?

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle doc also states:

*Note: There was a known bug in the Linux Kernel that may cause the JVM to crash when being t with -XX:UseNUMA. The bug was fixed in 2012, so this should not affect the latest versions of the Linux Kernel. To see if your Kernel has this bug, you can run the [native reproducer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/reproducer.c).*

Which I have reproduced here to demonstrate its simplicity:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/reproducer.c

To build the reproducer, you may need to install the **numactl** or **numactl-devel** packages depending on your distribution. See `man numa_maps` for details.

```
#include <numaif.h>
#include <numa.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
   if (numa_all_nodes_ptr == (void*)0) {
     return -1;
   }

   size_t pagesize = getpagesize();

   void* mapped_memory = mmap(NULL, 3 * pagesize, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
   if (mapped_memory == MAP_FAILED) {
     return -2;
   }

   void* page0 = mapped_memory;
   void* page1 = (void*)((uintptr_t)page0 + pagesize);
   void* page2 = (void*)((uintptr_t)page1 + pagesize); 

 // Set up the last page as interleaved.
   mbind(page2, pagesize, MPOL_INTERLEAVE, numa_all_nodes_ptr->maskp,
numa_all_nodes_ptr->size, 0);

   // Setup the last two pages as interleaved.
   mbind(page1, 2 * pagesize, MPOL_INTERLEAVE,
numa_all_nodes_ptr->maskp, numa_all_nodes_ptr->size, 0);

   *((char*)page2) = 2;
   *((char*)page1) = 1;
   *((char*)page0) = 0; // Crash here, when mbind_merge was broken.

   return 0;
}
```

So, I took the ambiguity to mean that 2.6.19 was the first **safe** version.

Comment: how do u compile this? where are the numa headers?

Comment: @Nik You may need to install numactl or numactl-devel according to man numa_maps 'Library support'